# Extracting a variable list of tags with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following `Resultset`:

```
<p>Cake</p><a>Cream</a><p>Coffee</p>
```

I also have a dictionary:

```
dic[0]='p'
dic[1]='a'
dic[2]='p'
```

How can I extract the values of my Resultset using my list? Ideally, I'd like to obtain a dictionary with

```
dic[0]='Cake'
dic[1]='Cream'
dic[2]='Coffee'
```

Basically, I want to search my `Resultset` continuously for the next tag in my list. I could use `find_all` but that means I'll manually have to map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = '''<p>Cake</p><a>Cream</a><p>Coffee</p>'''

dic = ['p', 'a', 'p']

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

i = iter(dic)

out = {i: tag.text for i, tag in enumerate(soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == next(i)))}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{0: 'Cake', 1: 'Cream', 2: 'Coffee'}
```

EDIT: Version if there are tags in ResultSet that aren't in search list:

```
data = '''<span>Don't search this</span>
            <p>Cake</p>
          <span>Don't search this</span>
            <a>Cream</a>
            <p>Coffee</p>'''

lst = ['p', 'a', 'p']

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

def search(lst):
    lst = lst[:]
    tag = yield
    while lst:
        if lst[0] == tag.name:
            lst.pop(0)
            tag = yield True
            continue
        tag = yield False

it = search(lst)
next(it)
out = {i: tag.text for i, tag in enumerate(soup.find_all(lambda t: it.send(t)))}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{0: 'Cake', 1: 'Cream', 2: 'Coffee'}
```

EDIT 2: Using CSS selector:

```
data = '''<span>Don't search this</span>
            <p>Cake</p>
          <span>Don't search this</span>
            <a>Cream</a>
            <p>Coffee</p>'''

lst = ['p', 'a', 'p']

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print({i: tag.text for i, tag in enumerate(soup.select(','.join(lst)))})
```

Prints:

```
{0: 'Cake', 1: 'Cream', 2: 'Coffee'}
```